# How to stop sweet/sugary dressings from ruining a baking dish?

Tags: baking, equipment, roast

Through trial and error I've discovered that squeezing a fresh lime over roast parsnips (prior to roasting) make the end product absoutely sublime.

The problem however is that the sticky sweet lime juice can make the baking tray hell to clean, or in one pectacular instance of 'over cooking' ruined the non-stick baking tray.

Any suggestions to help stop honey glaze and other sweet / sugary dressings from ruining roast dishes?

Thanks.

P.S. Free free to close if this is off topic :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could cover the baking tray with a sheet of parchment paper.

Comment: Tin foil may also work but I recommend using parchment or baking paper instead!

Comment: What do you mean by parchement paper? We don't have that in Ireland, or it goes by a different name. Would "Grease Proof" paper mean anything to you? A whitish, opaque, waxy paper that you'd use to line cake tins?

Comment: @Binary Worrier: Parchment paper is coated with silicone, and is heat-safe.  Wax paper is coated with wax which will melt if cooking with it.  (And there's 'dry' wax paper, so it's not all greasy feeling).   As you said you bake with it, if it doesn't make the cake taste like crayons, it's probably okay.